# Is there a hadith saying something like "Fear the man/person who leaves everything to Allah"?

Tags: hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Is there a hadith that says something like "Fear the man/person who leaves everything to Allah"

Somebody here in India told me in hindi in words like: "Daro us shakhs (i.e. human) se jo apnay muaamlaat Allah par chor daita hai"

I mean something like: When someone hurts or harms this person, he leaves it to Allah to do justice; so the hadith says that we should fear this person.

Comment: The statement is far too vague I have at least one hadith in mind that comes close to that.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Please share the one that comes to your mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Medi1Saif is referring to:

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Allah said, '**I will declare war against him who shows hostility to a pious worshipper of Mine**. And the most beloved things with which My slave comes nearer to Me, is what I have enjoined upon him; and My slave keeps on coming closer to Me through performing Nawafil (praying or doing extra deeds besides what is obligatory) till I love him, so I become his sense of hearing with which he hears, and his sense of sight with which he sees, and his hand with which he grips, and his leg with which he walks; and if he asks Me, I will give him, and if he asks My protection (Refuge), I will protect him; (i.e. give him My Refuge) and I do not hesitate to do anything as I hesitate to take the soul of the believer, for he hates death, and I hate to disappoint him." (Sahih al-Bukhari https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/91)

Allah also says in the qur'an:

> Unquestionably, [for] the allies of Allah there will be no fear concerning them, nor will they grieve (10:62 https://quranx.com/10.62)

Another hadith which was mentioned in ibn Hajar's commentary which goes along to the meaning of this one is:

> ...  I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: ‘A little showing off is polytheism and **whoever shows enmity towards a friend of Allah has declared war on Allah**. Allah loves those who se righteousness and piety are hidden, those who, if they are absent, are not missed, and if they are present, they are not invited or acknowledged. Their hearts are lamps of guidance and they get out of every trial and difficulty.’” (Sunan ibn Majah https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/36/64)

Comment: Yeah the first was my first thought. But I don't know if OP is looking for that one.

Comment: @Medi1Saif This was very helpful. It served the purpose. May Allah give reward to both of you inshaAllah

Comment: @Shy if you found an answer helpful you should accept or up-vote it. See also in our [help page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: @Sassir When I try to upvote an answer, it gives me **"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."** Likewise, it simply does not give me the option of upvoting _comments_ at all.

Comment: @Sassir Jazak Allah khair =)